# I've created a simple discord bot which is fetching how many users in a channel, now I want to put this data on a react front end. How?

Tags: reactjs, discord.js

Currently I have a very simple bot set up using the discord.js API.

What would be the next step to get the value of `membersCount` into a react front end? My file hierarchy is a create-react-app with a bots folder where this code lives inside `bot.js`.
Can I somehow export this variable here and import it into the front end or will I require some kind of express server?

````
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const myIntents = new Intents();
myIntents.add(Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS);
const client = new Client({ intents: myIntents });
//Scythe Gaming
client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.username}`)
    const id = "832452520211251260"
    
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.find((g) => g.id === id);
    let membersCount = 0;

    if (!guild) return console.log(`Can't find any guild with the ID "${id}"`);

    guild.members
    .fetch()
    .then((members) => {
    members.forEach((member) => membersCount++)
    console.log(` Guild member count: ${membersCount}`)},
);
});```
````

Comment: I think this article answers your question pretty well: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-the-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Express.js library for node and something like the axios library for react. Express will let you expose an API which axios can access. Expose the data you want to send to your frontend with Express, and fetch it using axios on the react side.
You can find here: [Link](https://www.bing.com/search?q=express%20docs&cvid=5d9789aecbfd43c6b1142b3eb05be465&aqs=edge..69i57j0l6.2621j0j1&pglt=43&FORM=ANNAB1&PC=U531)
and axios here: [Link](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro)